# knitr plotting code chunks to be seen and run

Tags: r, knitr

I've been trying to solve the following problem using `knitr`.
In `\LaTeX` I wish to define a chunk (once) called `myplot`.
Then I want to say something such as:

The code

```
<<myplot, tidy = FALSE>>=
plot(runif(9), runif(9),
     xlab = "x",
     ylab = "y",)
@
```

results in `Figure~\ref{fig:myownlabel}`.

```
\begin{figure}[hh]
\begin{center}
<<myplotfig, out.width='.50\\linewidth', width=6.6, height=4.8, echo=FALSE>>=
par(las = 1, mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(5, 4, 1, 1)+0.1)
<<myplot>>
@
\caption{
I insist to have the caption in \LaTeX.
\label{fig:myownlabel}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I know how to do it in Sweave but cannot seem to do it in `knitr`.
That is, the code chunk is seen by the reader.
Can you give me any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.
Thomas

Comment: Thanks very much Yihui for your quick response, it solved my problem. Am quite pleased with things now :)

Answer (score 4):

This is one difference between `knitr` and Sweave: Sweave does not keep plots by default (unless you specify `fig=TRUE`), but `knitr` does (unless you really do not want them, using `fig.keep='none'`).

```
<<myplot, tidy = FALSE, fig.keep = 'none'>>=
plot(runif(9), runif(9),
     xlab = "x",
     ylab = "y",)
@

\begin{figure}[hh]
\begin{center}
<<myplotfig, out.width='.50\\linewidth', fig.width=6.6, fig.height=4.8, echo=FALSE>>=
par(las = 1, mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(5, 4, 1, 1)+0.1)
<<myplot>>
@
\caption{
I insist to have the caption in \LaTeX.
\label{fig:myownlabel}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Although the problem has been solved so far, I have a few other comments:

1. when you use `knitr` (`>= 1.1`), you should be able to see a warning about the syntax of your code chunks, and you are required to call `Sweave2knitr()` to fix the problems; you will realize `width` and `height` are not valid chunk options in `knitr` (use `fig.width` and `fig.height`); see [here for more information](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/)
2. for the chunk `myplot`, I would use `eval=FALSE` because you probably do not want to evaluate the code twice;
3. with `knitr`, you can actually do everything through chunk options, e.g.

   ```
   <<myplot, tidy=FALSE, eval=FALSE, echo=-1>>=
   @
   <<myplot, out.width='.5\\linewidth', fig.width=6.6, fig.height=4.8, fig.align='center', echo=FALSE, fig.pos='hh', fig.cap='I insist to have the caption in \\LaTeX.'>>=
   par(las = 1, mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(5, 4, 1, 1)+0.1)
   plot(runif(9), runif(9),
        xlab = "x",
        ylab = "y",)
   @
   ```

   this gives you both the `center` and `figure` environments, and produces a label `fig:myplot` automatically.

Comment: @agstudy the nested chunks are for reusing code so you do not have to repeat some code over two chunks: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/

Comment: Thanks! excellent! I asked this because when I try your code, the code was well indented . Side note Did you finish your book about `knitr` ?

Comment: @agstudy yes, and I think the book has been available for one week, although I have not received a copy myself yet; the indentation was due to the fact that the original code was well indented, and `tidy=FALSE` told `knitr` do not reformat the code